# Java Threading: Unexpected Results

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose in have 3 threads main, task1, and task2 and I've not called join on both of them. I was expecting, if the main thread finishes first, the program will be terminated. Right?

```java
class Task1 extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("task 1");
    }
}

class Task2 extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10_000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        System.out.println("task 2");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Thread th1 = new Task1();
            Thread th2 = new Task2();

            System.out.println("main thread starts");

            th1.start();
            th2.start();

            System.out.println("main thread ends");
        }
}
```

Suppose in have 3 threads main, task1, and task2 and I've not called join on both of them. I was expecting, if the main thread finishes first, the program will be terminated. Right?

That's not happening here In fact the terminal hangs for the 10 secs and then the program is terminated. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each thread has a boolean property called 'daemon'. A new thread by default is not daemon. You can make it daemon: `t.setDaemon(true);`. In official parlance, the opposite of a daemon thread is a user thread.

The JVM exits when **zero running/frozen user threads exist**, i.e.: The only threads on the entire system fall into one of three categories:

- Are `setDaemon(true)` status
- Haven't been started yet
- Have finished

Simply make your threads daemon status if you intend for them not to interrupt JVM exit.

Note that more generally this entire system is **strongly** not recommended. If you want a JVM to exit, call `System.exit(0)`. Any notions of 'but.. cleanup and nice shutdown!' are misleading / bad. It's not a good idea to think about the warning your OS gives when you yank an old USB stick out as something to aspire to! Proper systems don't *need* cleanup.

Note that many system resources (TCP/IP, files, etc) are cleaned up by the OS if your JVM exits: No need to do it in java code. Pipes too, so there go DB connections - no need there either. That leaves files with state which optimally should be designed e.g. via journalling systems to just recover perfectly every time.

After all, you can't guarantee nice cleanup. What if someone trips over a power cord? What if some JNI code coredumps (which insta-kills the JVM?)

To summarize JVM cleanup etiquette:

- Do not rely on 'JVM exits if all non-daemon threads are done' to shut down JVMs. This leads to bad user experience where your app fails to shut down upon request because you forgot about some thread.
- In general the notion of 'but, cleanup!' is bad. Spend time writing software that doesn't need it. Modern OSes haven't needed for well over a decade now.
- If you have specific cleanup anyway and you aren't capable of figuring out a way to make it cleanup-free, the correct answer is a shutdown hook (`Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook()`). You still, and always, exit a JVM by calling `System.exit`, **never** by relying on the 'it shuts itself down if all non-daemon threads end' functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is correct. Programm will stop **only** when **all not daemon** threads will be stopped.

```java
Thread th1 = new Task1();
Thread th2 = new Task2();

System.out.println("main thread starts");

th1.start();
th2.start();

System.out.println("main thread ends");
```

**Output:**

```
main thread starts
main thread ends
task 1
task 2
```

---

```java
Thread th1 = new Task1();
Thread th2 = new Task2();

System.out.println("main thread starts");

th1.start();
th2.start();

th1.join();
th2.join();

System.out.println("main thread ends");
```

**Output:**

```
main thread starts
task 1
task 2
main thread ends
```

---

```java
Thread th1 = new Task1();
Thread th2 = new Task2();

th1.setDaemon(true);
th2.setDaemon(true);

System.out.println("main thread starts");

th1.start();
th2.start();

System.out.println("main thread ends");
```

Output:

```
main thread starts
main thread ends
task 1
```

***Note:** Thread 2 will be terminated.*